# Is it possible to make vim behave more like a python IDE?

Tags: python, vim, ide

Are there any commands in vimscript or any extensions that I could use?

I already use syntax highlighting but I was hoping for error highlighting or warnings if thats possible.

Comment: Entering "python vim IDE" into Google renders this great [blog post](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) as the top result. Everything you could possibly want, I'd say...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things you can do to improve it.

For static error highlighting/warnings I use PyFlakes: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441

And if you want some more intelligence I would recommend using Ropevim: http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropevim.html

The things that Rope will give you:

- Rename
- Extract method/local variable
- Move class/function/module/package/method
- Inline method/local variable/parameter
- Restructuring
- Change signature

Other refactoring-related features:

- Previewing refactorings
- Undo/redo refactorings
- Showing refactoring progress

Code-assists:

- Code-completion
- Goto definition
- Show pydoc
- Find occurrences
- Organize imports (remove unused and duplicate imports and sort them)
- Generating python elements